# Legend not showing using geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this data set and code

```
a <- data.frame(x=seq(1,100,1), y=rnorm(100))
b <- data.frame(x=seq(1,100,1), y=rnorm(100))

graph1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_smooth(data = a, aes(x,y),
              method = lm, formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = FALSE,
              color = "red", linewidth = 0.4, show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_smooth(data = b, aes(x,y),
              method = lm, formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = FALSE,
              color = "blue", linewidth = 0.4, show.legend = TRUE)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="",values = c("red", "blue"),
                      labels=c("Legend 1","Legend 1"))
```

Even using the `show.legend = TRUE` command, the graph is not showing the legend
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpSnj.png)